# Is there a way to fade in background colors using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with onClick (colorRefresh) and the script works fine but I would like to know if I could fade it in.

```
 function colorRefresh()
{ body[0].style.backgroundImage = `linear-gradient(to right, rgb(${colorOne[0]},${colorOne[1]},${colorOne[2]}),rgb(${colorTwo[0]},${colorTwo[1]},${colorTwo[2]})).fadeIn()`;
}
```

I tried to use `fadeIn()` but nothing happens. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: jQueryUI can also animate colors. Or you write your own "fade" function for colors (-> [HSL and HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)

Comment: Thanks but it's still not working: `body[0].style.backgroundImage.animate('linear-gradient(to right, rgb(${colorOne[0]},${colorOne[1]},${colorOne[2]}),rgb(${colorTwo[0]},${colorTwo[1]},${colorTwo[2]}))');` I guess I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS3 <body> background-color change linear infinite animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42074733/css3-body-background-color-change-linear-infinite-animation)

Comment: @Triby I do want to animate it, but with Javascript if possible

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963059/jquery-animate-div-background-color-gradient

Comment: How would I do something more like a transition?